# Junit 5 test, getting java.lang.IllegalStateException: Test classes cannot include @Bean methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean, junit5

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigureCustomConfigurationModelProviderTest.class)
    public class ConfigureCustomConfigurationModelProviderTest extends AbstractContextTest {
        @Bean(name = "smth")
        public static ConfigurationModelProvider get() {
            return AnnotationConfigurationModelProvider.getInstance();
        }
        /*...*/
    }
```

I'm getting this error since migrating from junit4 to junit5. Why?

Comment: spring version please

Comment: Well, if it's 4.3, look at this: https://github.com/sbrannen/spring-test-junit5

Comment: What does `AbstractContextTest` look like?

Answer (score 17):

You should move every `bean`s to `@Configuration` class for example `TestConfig`:

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {

    @Bean(name = "smth")
    public static ConfigurationModelProvider get() {
        return AnnotationConfigurationModelProvider.getInstance();
    }
}
```

and import it via `@Import`:

```
@Import({TestConfig.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = ConfigureCustomConfigurationModelProviderTest.class)
public class ConfigureCustomConfigurationModelProviderTest extends AbstractContextTest {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to Amir's answer: if you only need the bean for some tests you can omit the @Configuration annotation at the top.